# Arranging problems so they will return side by side

Tags: python, string, list

For this project, I am trying to arrange the input from this function:

```
arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"])
```

So it looks like this:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

There are four spaces in between each problem. By my results keep printing like this:

```
   32
+ 698
-----
  730,  3801
-    2
------
  3799,  45
+ 43
----
  88,  123
+  49
-----
  172,
```

This is my code:

```
def arth(x, solve):
    fnlStr = ""
    for item in x:
        arth = item.split()
        val1 = int(arth[0])
        val2 = int(arth[2])
        len1 = len(arth[0])
        len2 = len(arth[2])

        if arth[1] == "+":
            sum = val1 + val2
        else:
            sum = val1 - val2

        if(len1 > len2):
            dash = len1 + 2
        else:
            dash = len2 + 2

        def strCrt(x, y, s):
            return(x.ljust(y, s))
        
        String = ""
        numL1 = dash - len1
        numL2 = dash - (len2 + 1)
        numL3 = dash - len(str(sum))

        lineStr = strCrt(String, dash, "-")
        spaceL1 = strCrt(String, numL1, " ")
        spaceL2 = strCrt(String, numL2, " ")
        spaceL3 = strCrt(String, numL3, " ")


        fnlStr += (f"{spaceL1}{val1}\n{arth[1]}{spaceL2}{val2}\n{lineStr}\n{spaceL3}{sum},")
    return(fnlStr)  

print(arth(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True))
```

The problem may start from how I return the string at the bottom, so I tried this:

```
        fnlArr.append(f"{spaceL1}{val1}\n{arth[1]}{spaceL2}{val2}\n{lineStr}\n{spaceL3}{sum},")
    return(fnlArr)
    

print(arth(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"], True))
```

But that still gave me some problems, returning this:

```
['   32\n+ 698\n-----\n  730,', '  3801\n-    2\n------\n  3799,', '  45\n+ 43\n----\n  88,', '  123\n+  49\n-----\n  172,']
```

How should I change up my code so it arranges the problems side by side and not below eachother or formatted wierd in a list? Any help would be greatly appriciated, i'm sorry for any simple errors in my code, I am very new. Thank you.

Comment: Start by converting `"32 + 8"` into a *list* of strings, like `["32", "+8"]`. Repeat for each sum; now you have a list of lists that you can zip together, e.g. turn `[["32", "+8"], ["1", "- 3801"], ...]` into `[["32", "1", ...], ["+8, "- 3801", ...]]`. This should be easier to turn into the side-by-side list of problems you want.

Comment: The point is that you want "horizontal composition", but standard output really only supports "vertical composition", so you need to think of your layout in terms of a series of rows to stack from top to bottom, rather than a series of columns to print left to right.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list where you put the split expression (using `str.split(maxsplit=1)`), the `---`-part and the result.

Then you can transpose this list (using `zip(*...)`) and print it line-by-line:

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(exprs):
    out = []
    for e in exprs:
        e = e.split(maxsplit=1)
        max_len = len(max(e, key=len))
        out.append(
            [f"{ee:>{max_len}}" for ee in e + ["-" * max_len, eval("".join(e))]]
        )

    for row in zip(*out):
        print("   ".join(row))


arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"])
```

Prints:

```
 32        1     9999    523
+ 8   - 3801   + 9999   - 49
---   ------   ------   ----
 40    -3800    19998    474
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def arithmetic_arranger(exprs):
    out = []
    for e in exprs:
        e = e.split(maxsplit=1)
        max_len = len(max(e, key=len))
        out.append(
            [f"{ee:>{max_len}}" for ee in e + ["-" * max_len, eval("".join(e))]]
        )

    for row in zip(*out):
        print("   ".join(row))


arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"])
```